# this query cannot execute fast, why?

Tags: mysql, performance

```
select 
  OQSP.query_id as quries_id, 
  OQA.allocation_date_time,
  OQA.submitted_date_time,
  OQA.comment,
  OQ.*,
  p.pnr_no,
  p.pnr_generated_time,
  p.mail_status,
  p.exp_mail_status,
  p.time_validity,
  p.payment_status,
  p.payment_type 
from online_query_submit_option OQSP 
left join online_query_allocation OQA on OQSP.query_id= OQA.alloted_query_id 
left join online_queries OQ on OQSP.query_id= OQ.query_id 
left join pnr_quries as p on p.query_id=OQ.query_id 
where 
1=1 
and (OQ.confirm IS NULL OR OQ.confirm='') 
and (OQ.dead IS NULL OR OQ.dead='') 
and (OQ.running IS NULL OR OQ.running='' 
OR OQ.running='running') 
and OQA.assigned_executive='swatijoshi' 
and OQA.exec_del_status=0 
and OQ.admin_del_status=0 
and OQA.submitted_query=1 
AND date(OQ.query_date)='2015-07-28' 
group by OQSP.query_id 
order by OQ.query_date DESC,OQSP.query_id DESC 
limit 0,5
```

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting the query.  It is unreadable.

Comment: i didn't understand formatting query, actually this is my original query that i run and this to slow why..........?

Comment: @ChandanKumar : [Go through this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You're left joining three tables with the first table and those tables presumably have a large amount of data and on top of that there are too many conditions (not something abnormal but it takes a hit in the performance) in the where clause. This effectively slows down your query.

Comment: i have a lot's of condition in where clause that is important. how can i fast this query is there any other sloution

Comment: if i use indexing in this query it execute fast..?

Comment: It **might** be faster - see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `LEFT` when you don't need it.

```
left join online_queries OQ on OQSP.query_id= OQ.query_id ...
AND date(OQ.query_date)='2015-07-28'
```

The `LEFT` says to keep missing rows from OQ; but then the `AND` will throw away any missing rows.

Change

```
AND date(OQ.query_date)='2015-07-28' 
group by OQSP.query_id 
order by OQ.query_date DESC,OQSP.query_id DESC 
limit 0,5
```

to

```
AND OQ.query_date >= '2015-07-28'
AND OQ.query_date  < '2015-07-28' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
group by OQ.query_date,
         OQ.query_id          -- added to match the ORDER BY
order by OQ.query_date DESC,
         OQ.query_id DESC     -- same as OQSP
limit 0,5
```

and add

```
INDEX(query_date, query_id)  -- to OQ
```

That way, the optimizer *might* be able to do the `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT` all very efficiently using the `INDEX`.

Please edit your question to include

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE -- for each table
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;
```

With those, we can dispense some more advice/abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but hopefully some useful tips:

Use EXPLAIN to work out how well your query is executing.

Check that all the fields that you are JOINing on are indexed, whether simply being a primary key or otherwise. Sometimes indexing some of the fields mentioned in the WHERE clause can also boost your query speed.

You may also want to reorder your JOINs; it looks as though your first step ought to be to get the OQA records as they will return a very limited set.

Is OQ.query_date a 'date' field or a 'datetime' field? If the former, you might not need to use date() around it. If it is defined as a VARCHAR for some reason, change it to a date field.